# Trying parse-server-mailgun

Tags: parse-server, mailgun

I am trying to follow this document:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-mailgun

When running this commande:

```
...$ node ./src/mailgun-tester
```

I get the following error:

```
...../node_modules/parse-server-mailgun/src/mailgun-tester/index.js:24
    User: class User {
          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Anyone knows what this is about?

Answer (score 0):

What version of node are you running? `node -v`

I had the same issue on a backup server running `mailgun-js` under node version `4.2.5` and updating node to `7.0.X` solved the issue.